# Order different data from different tables in the same SQL query

Tags: mysql, pagination

I am new to web development, working on a first school project.
I am trying to make an activity page, showing all recent activity of an user in a social network.
I need to obtain data from different tables like `posts`, `comments`, `likes`, `messages`. I need to order them by date and use pagination.
I thought I could use four different statements and then merge the resulting arrays, but I can't take all that data just to throw it away because of pagination, so I need `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` statements.
The SQL statement I need is something like this:

```
SELECT posts.stuff, comments.this, messages.that
FROM posts, comments, messages
ORDER BY ?????
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

How do I order these by date? Does it help if all tables have a column called `date` for the date?

Using MySQL, PHP and Bootstrap for pagination.

Thank you :D

**EDIT**

These are the tables I have to take data from:

```
[posts]
idPosts
title <--
description <--
date <--
`by` (FK) <--
category (FK) <--
"WHERE `by`= '$user_id'"

[comments]
idComments
comment <--
date <--
post (FK) <--
`by` (FK) <--
"WHERE `by` = '$user_id'"

[likes]
idLikes
date <--
post (FK) <--
`by` (FK) <--
"WHERE `by` = '$user_id'"

[messages]
idMessages
message <--
date <--
`by` (FK) <--
`to` (FK) <--
"WHERE `by` = '$user_id' OR to = '$user_id'"

this_is_a_foreign_key (FK)
and
i_need_this_column_out_of_the_query <--
```

Plus, I should know which `SELECT` statement a certain row comes from, so I can represent it in an appropriate way.

Is this possible anyhow?
Thanks :)

No one knows how to get a such result?? :/

Comment: So you're not interested in any relationship which may exist between these tables

Comment: @Strawberry, How do you tell it? I am just reading entries for now, it seemed the right way to me

Comment: No one knows how to get a such result?? :/

Answer (score 1):

Use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), then wrap it in a sub-query so you can order them all by date.

It would look like this:

```
SELECT action
FROM (

    SELECT stuff AS action  --I'll use action as the column name
        , actionDate        --assuming that this is the column name of the date
        FROM posts

    UNION ALL               --because UNION only removes duplicate

    SELECT this
        , actionDate
        FROM comments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT that
        , actionDate
        FROM messages
) AS activities
ORDER BY actionDate 
LIMIT 10                    --no need for OFFSET if it is zero
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :) There is a problem, `UNION ALL` requires all `SELECT` statements to have the same amount of columns, and unfortunately that's not my case. Is there an other way I could use `UNION`? I continue coming with new ideas but always have to discard them XD ps: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` will be variables

Comment: @OmarElHajj Yes, the 3 tables should have the same number of columns, because you cannot `ORDER` them if you will not `UNION` them. Otherwise, show us the design of the 3 tables, and the resulting table you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show us the result data that you want? An example will be good. Because I do not know if it is okay to exclude some columns from the tables. We can also find a way to represent from which table the row comes from.

By the way, I do not know what do you mean by `i_am_trying_to_take_this <--`

Comment: with `<--` I meant the columns that I need for the page; I think that something like what would come out of your above example would be good. All I need is al paginated list of recent activity of the user, so a such result should be manageable.

Comment: I get it now. I'll try to answer your question